# Long press handling on android app icon

Tags: android

Need to handle long press (key + touch) on adroid app icon.
Click + key press events in android apps are for controls + views. 
But in my case needs to handle long touch(press) on application ICON.

Please suggest

Answer (score 2):

You can try this [AppShortcuts](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/shortcuts.html). After few years it's possible!

Answer (score 1):

If you mean an application icon in launcher or home screen then you can do nothing to deal with: touch events go to the application which IS a home screen or launcher.